# How to get drawcall and tris info through script?

Tags: unity-game-engine

Who can tell me how to get drawcall and tris info by script？now I want to show drawcall and tris info in my iphone，I make a UIPanel that has text component to show this info,but now i can't get this info,who can help me? i know how to get by UnityEditor,but UnityEditor can't enable in Mobile phone.I can get it by UnityStats in editor mode. What can i do now?i only want get this infos to show in my ios devices.

Comment: i would recommend the Unity Profiler to get those informations.

Comment: who can teach me how to do?I am chinese, i like make friends and my english is bad,may i make friends with you?

Comment: follow those guides http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Profiler.html or http://blog.collectivemass.com/2014/03/unity-profiler-ios/

Comment: i will,what about make friends？let me look that blog

Comment: Hello JeanLuc，I had readed that blog，I know that methods，but it's not suit

Comment: I know that methods，buy i want to show this info in my iphone when i not front of computer，example walk on road,when i open this game,i can show everyone my current game,i also can watch the drawcall info in my text component,

Comment: yes, the Unity Profiler requires a connection to your computer. sorry for not helping :-)

Comment: no matter,what about make friends?we can talk about unity ,also i can learn from you~

Comment: sorry, no, I don't have that much time. If you have a question about unity: do your research first for at least a day and then ask a proper question on stackoverflow, then I might be happy to help.

Comment: ok,thanks very much.have a nice day